# Can I submit apps to Appstore for Submission if they are built using a beta version of Xcode such as Xcode 6.3?

Tags: ios, xcode

Can I submit apps to Appstore for Submission if they are built using a beta version of Xcode?

Comment: Why don't you use the non-beta version of Xcode 6.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use beta versions of Xcode to submit apps to either store. However Xcode 6.3 is now out of beta so you can use it now.

You can, however, always develop projects in a beta version of Xcode and try building it in the current release version to submit to the store (which will sometimes work) or wait until the beta gets released to submit your project.